# Can you pass a name into a Join Meeting link in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a system where meetings are created in Teams by a fully authenticated Teams user.
The link for the meeting is published in our web app and visible to the people (clients) it's intended for.

The clients are unauthenticated/external/"anonymous" as far as Teams is concerned.

When they join the meeting Teams asks them to enter their names.

They have accessed the meeting link through our system, so we know their name.

My question is - can we supply the name of the user in our system into the Join meeting link in some way so that they don't need to type their name in Teams?

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate on behalf user? if yes, please check [Get access on behalf user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user), by using this you can authenticate on behalf user

Comment: Hi @Nikitha-MSFT, no, the users being sent the meeting link will simply have a link in their app, and click it to join the meeting as themselves. As per Teams functionality they will be asked to type their name within Teams - my question is - can we specify their name as part of the meeting link, so when they click to join the meeting the name is already completed.

Comment: No, You cannot specify the user name in the meeting link. This is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently You cannot specify the user name in the meeting link. This is by design.